# how do i move a file from downloads folder to opt folder?

Tags: directory

i cant move john-1.7.9.tar.gz from downloads folder to opt folder, i tried

```
sudo cp -r /home/kevsfernandez/downloads john-1.7.9.tar.gz /opt
```

and just says

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/kevsfernandez/downloads’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘john-1.7.9.tar.gz’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9):

Go to your download files with this command:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
```

Then run this command to copy the file to the `/opt` directory:

```
$ sudo cp john-1.7.9.tar.gz /opt/
```

By the way, you are most likely getting the error file not found error message because you don't have a `downloads` directory.  You have a `Downloads` directory.  The files and directory names in Linux are case sensitive.  Those are two different directory names.  You can have two different folders by those names on Linux, but they would be the same directory in Windows.

Also, in the future when you have a problem copy exactly what you type and the exact error message and paste it to your question.  This would make it easier for the community to see the exact problem.

Please, also consider formatting your quoted text with a one of the formatting provisions such as the `''` or the `{}` tools above.  You can do this by highlighting the text you want formatted then clicking on one of the `markdown links`.

---

**Detailed explanation of the specific errors**

After the reformatted text of your question it's clear that you have two errors.  One of your errors is the misspelling of your downloads folder name.  You specified "downloads" where no folder or file by that name exist.  It should have been `Downloads` (with the capital D).  The first of your two errors is saying you don't have a "downloads" folder.

The second of your two errors is that you have a space in your pathname.  The space is indicating that you are trying to copy two files, one called `/home/kevsfernandez/downloads` and one called ‘john-1.7.9.tar.gz’ to your `/opt/` folder.

When you specify more than one two arguments, all except the last argument is a list of files to be copied to the last argument.

The answer I gave above resolves the problem.